# Python for ArcGIS: Code refuses to accept a defined variable as input

Tags: arcpy

I'm learning to use arcpy, and I am starting to try and script some geoprocessing tools.

While trying to use `arcpy.Select_analysis`, I found that the code does not accept a defined variable as input. If (and only if) I directly type my file location into the initial input, will the code work. Once I try to define the file location as a variable, the script tells me that the dataset is not supported. This doesn't make sense to me - I copied the file location correctly, nothing has changed except that I defined it as a variable. I even changed the variable name a number of times, just in case.

This is the initial code:

```
import arcpy
inLayer='file_path'
outLayer='output_dir'
arcpy.Select_analysis('inLayer', 'outLayer', '"CNTRY_NAME"=\'Mexico\'')
```

The only way I've managed to make it work is to do:

```
import arcpy  
arcpy.Select_analysis('file_path', 'output_dir', '"CNTRY_NAME"=\'Mexico\'')
```

**Edit:** 
Actually I was using both inLayer and outLayer with `arcpy.GetParameterAsText()`
But to try and figure this out I changed it all to filenames instead.
My paths were `file_path=r'C:\LabData'`

Again, it worked when I put it directly into the code, but not when I defined it as a variable.

This error carries over when I define the variable to accept user input; no matter what I do, the initial step refuses to take any input and just says that the dataset is not supported.

I couldn't find anything similar to that (or I was searching the wrong terms) on here so I was hoping someone could help.

Comment: Hi durelen, could you edit your question to include the code you have been trying?

Comment: Show your code.  Without code no one will agree with your analysis or conclusion, since it cannot be independently tested.  With custom code the presumption always is that you are making the mistake, not Python, until it is replicated by others and no alternative approach is available to solve the problem.

Comment: Can you add an example of your file paths. Are you adding the double backslash or the preceding 'r'?

Comment: remove the single quotes from around the input and output variable names inLayer and outLayer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting your workspace, and reference datasets in your workspace. http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/using-environment-settings.htm

Also, I just realized your inLayer and outLayer were in quotes, so python was attempting to look for a feature literally called inLayer.

The following is an example of setting the workspace, but referencing the full filepath to the shapefile or feature class you're working with is perfectly fine.

```
import arcpy
workspace = r'filepath\gdb.gdb' #if you're working with shapefiles, just filepath
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
inLayer = "featureName"
outLayer = inLayer + "_select"
arcpy.Select_analysis(inLayer, outLayer, '"CNTRY_NAME"=\'Mexico\'')
```